# How to access textfield in tableviewCell from another method

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm building an app that allows the user to insert products and information about those products. all information on one products is inserted in different textfields in a custom `TableViewCell`. I need to create a 2-dimensional array of products because Later on, I want to use that array to insert each product into a database.

To create that array, I need my app to save the text from each textfield every time the user stops entering a textfield. The problem is, I can not create a `textFieldDidEndEditing` method for a specific textfield.

so put it shortly:

When I have more textfields in one `UITableViewCell`, How to access all of these textfields individually from another method (preferably with a `textFieldDidEndEditing` method)?

Comment: you can check for specific textField in textFieldDidEndEditing.

Comment: assign tag to ur textfield. and use that tag to access that textfield.

Comment: @BSThakrar you'd make my day if you could only explain how. i'm probably missing something simple, but I'm a beginner so I'm afraid i need some help here and there.

Comment: r u creating textField by storyboard or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by two ways
1) Assign tag value to each textfield
2) give restoration id to each text field

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     if([textField.restorationIdentifier isEqualToString:@"YourID"])
     {
        //store in array
     }
           OR 
    if(textField.tag == 1)
    {
        //store in array.
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems to work.. Sorry I had to do more that just insert some code to make this work, but your answer solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

assign tag to your textfield. and use that tag to access that textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You add method in UItextField :

```
[textfield addTarget:self action:@selector(textfieldcall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
textfield.tag=100;
```

call this method

```
-(void)textfieldcall:(UITextField*)sender
{
    if (sender.tag==100) {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```